# WebMVC tests failing after adding spring security, how to fix all at once?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I just added `spring-boot-starter-security` and `spring-security-test` to my Spring Boot application. I want to protect controllers and methods.

Now all my controller tests (`@WebMvcTest`) are all failing. It seems that all GET methods fail with 401 and all POST/DELETE/PUT fail with 403.

I can easily fix the 401 by using `@WithMockUser`.

What is the easiest way to get all tests running again? I don't want to consider security in these tests. Later i want to add specific tests for security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Security automatically adds CSRF defense to every POST, DELETE, and PUT request, so that is why you are seeing the 403.

You can [disable CSRF protection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-configure), though this is an important defense mechanism, so disabling isn't generally recommended. Spring Security has some information in their reference docs for how to determine [when CSRF protection is necessary](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#when-to-use-csrf-protection).

Instead, you can have Spring Security [add in a test CSRF token to your tests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc-csrf) by configuring your Mock Mvc instance:

```
this.mockMvc.perform(post("/").with(csrf()))
```

Where `csrf()` is from `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors`.

Note that the reason your tests are failing will be the same reason that POSTs, etc. will fail in your application - they will also be [expecting a CSRF token as part of the request](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-using).

Comment: thanks, that means i have to change all tests. At the moment i want test concerns separated. tests that test functionality and test that check security.